# Install custom control on VB.NET 2010?

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

I have created a custom control and now I have to create an installation package which integrates my control into the VB IDE (adds it into the toolbox). The issue is that I have no idea where the DLL file should be placed and how to "register" it so it shows along with the other controls. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1) Open your custom control and create it (<kbd>F7</kbd>)

Step 2) Open the project, you want to add it to

Step 3) Right-click in your Toolbox > Select Elements > Browse > ...[yourproject]\bin\Debug[yourcontrol].dll > Open